# Password remember dialog not showing in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

In My project i have used angular js and ruby on rails(REST Client). When I login in, browser doesn't ask me to save password.
Instead when i logout from the website, that time it asks me to save password.

My html code

```
<form action="#login" method="post" name="candidate_loginform" id="candidate_loginform" ng-submit="Login(candidate_loginform);"  novalidate onsubmit="return false;">
     <input id="log" type="text" name="log" ng-model="login.email" required placeholder="User Id"/>
     <input id="pwd" type="password" name="pwd" ng-model="login.password" required placeholder="Password"/>  
     <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-green full-width">        
</form>
```

The above code works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome if fails.

I tried all possible solutions found on stackoverflow and ended till here. I am using angularjs 1.2.28. My login code:

```
var transform = function(data) {
    return $.param(data);
};
    $http.post(rest_url+'users/sign_in', {'user':$scope.login},{
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
        transformRequest: transform
    }).success(function(data){
        $location.path("/dashboard");
    }).error(function(data){
        hideLoader();
        error_notification(data.message);
    });
```

Comment: Did you check in chrome if that setting is enabled ... some of the plugins like password manger disables it

Comment: yes , i checked its enabled.

Comment: `onsubmit="return false;"` try removing this

Comment: my problem solved by refreshing page after login.